# Let $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ such that $f(x)=x^6-1,x\in\Bbb Q$ and $f(x)=1-x^6,x\in\Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Q.$ Find the points where $f$ is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, proof-writing

Let $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ such that $f(x)=x^6-1,x\in\Bbb Q$ and $f(x)=1-x^6,x\in\Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Q.$ Find the points where $f$ is discontinuous and continuous.

I tried solving this problem as follows:

Let $x\in\Bbb Q\setminus \{-1,1\}$ then, $\exists (x_n)\subseteq \Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$ such that $\lim x_n=x.$ Now, $\lim f(x_n)=\lim (1-x_n^6)=1-x^6\neq x^6-1=f(x),$ when $x\neq -1,1.$ So, $f$ is discontinuous at all rational points except $\{-1,1\}.$

If $x\in\Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Q$, then, $\exists (x_n)\subseteq \Bbb Q$ such that $\lim x_n=x.$ Now, $\lim f(x_n)=\lim (x_n^6-1)=x^6-1\neq 1-x^6=f(x),$ when $x\neq -1,1.$ So, $f$ is discontinuous at all irrational points.

Let $x=1.$ Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence such that $\lim x_n=1.$ Now, $\lim f(x_n)=x_n^6-1,$ if $x_n\in\Bbb Q$ or $\lim f(x_n)=1-x_n^6,$ if $x_n\in\Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Q.$ In either case, $\lim x_n^6-1=\lim 1-x_n^6=0=f(1),$ so $f$ is continuous at $1.$

Let $x=-1.$ Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence such that $\lim x_n=-1.$ Now, $\lim f(x_n)=x_n^6-1,$ if $x_n\in\Bbb Q$ or $\lim f(x_n)=1-x_n^6,$ if $x_n\in\Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Q.$ In either case, $\lim x_n^6-1=\lim 1-x_n^6=0=f(-1),$ so $f$ is continuous at $-1.$

So, the only points where $f$ is continuous is $\{-1,1\}.$

---

In my solution I am not sure, if the way I concluded that $f$ is continuous at $\{-1,1\}$ is correct or not. The way I've written the things out there i.e

> Now, $\lim f(x_n)=x_n^6-1,$ if $x_n\in\Bbb Q$ or $\lim f(x_n)=1-x_n^6,$ if $x_n\in\Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Q.$ In either case, $\lim x_n^6-1=\lim 1-x_n^6=0=f(1),$ so $f$ is continuous at $1.$

and

> Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence such that $\lim x_n=-1.$ Now, $\lim f(x_n)=x_n^6-1,$ if $x_n\in\Bbb Q$ or $\lim f(x_n)=1-x_n^6,$ if $x_n\in\Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Q.$ In either case, $\lim x_n^6-1=\lim 1-x_n^6=0=f(-1),$ so $f$ is continuous at $-1.$

seems a bit confusing for I don't know whether this can be considered a formal way of writing the proof? Any suggestions regarding my proof-writing will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're right that those parts of the argument are flawed because a sequence can contain both rational and irrational elements. Use the definition of continuity instead (or the definition of limits). When in doubt, you always have the definitions.

Comment: Also, if the same argument applies at both 1 and -1 (which it does in this case), you can just state that instead of writing it out again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sequence $(x_n)$ could have both rational and irrational terms. Thus the parts you quoted are not correct. An easier way out is to use the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of continuity.

We can also make it work with sequences. Consider any sequence $(x_n) \to 1$ or $-1$. Then exactly one of the following three happens:

1. $\exists N$ such that $x_n|_{n > N}$ are all rational
2. $\exists N$ such that $x_n|_{n > N}$ are all irrational
3. There are infinite rational and irrational terms.

In cases $(1)$ and $(2)$, it is easy to prove that the sequence converges to $f(x)$.

In case (3), consider two disjoint subsequences, $(y_m)$ of rationals and $(z_m)$ of irrationals - such that their "union" is $(x_n)$. Each of those subsequences converges to $x$, and their function converges to $f(x)$. Therefore, given any $\epsilon$ consider
$P$ and $Q$  such that 
for ${m>P}$, $|y_m - f(x)| < \epsilon $ and 
for ${m>Q}$, $|z_m - f(x)| < \epsilon $

Then consider $N = \max \{P, Q \}$; so that we have $|x_n  - f(x)| < \epsilon $ for all ${n>N}$